# Robot in Stage with two Infrared Sensors

Tags: simulation, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to simulate a robot, in the stage, with two infra-red sensors, is it possible? I tried to put two Laser Range Finders with only one measurement, but it didn't result!

Someone can help me?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59481/robot-in-stage-with-two-infrared-sensors/) by [MiguelRobPinto](https://answers.ros.org/users/2036/miguelrobpinto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-03-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two Sharp GP2D12 IR sensor for my old roomba-create project.
This is the setting for the sensor in the world file, they will use the same interface as laser.
You can adjust the fov depending on your actual setup on the robot.

```
define GD2D12 ranger
(
  sensor(
    range [ 0.10 0.8 ]
    fov 180.0
    samples 2
  )
  size [ 0.02 0.04 0.02 ]
)
```

---

Originally posted by [bombilee](https://answers.ros.org/users/4584/bombilee/) with karma: 86 on 2013-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1